# Enumerating table with parent-child relationships with non-standard numbering

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (let's name it person) with two columns

```
id, parent_id
```

I want to enumerate each record but assign a sub-number for every record where parent_id is not null e.g.

```
id | parent_id| number 
 1     NULL       1
 2     NULL       2
 3       2        2.1
 4     NULL       3
 5       4        3.1
```

Parents should have consecutive numbers in order by `id`, children - successive numbers starting with 1 for each parent. A parent may have many children. But the child can't have a child so 3.3.3 is not a case. 
What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Your expected output is not clear, why would 3,2 give 2.1 and why would 5,4 give 3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do this using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       concat_ws('.',
                 dense_rank() over (order by coalesce(parent_id, id)),
                 (case when parent_id is not null
                       then row_number() over (partition by parent_id order by id)
                  end)
                )
from person t
order by id;
```

Comment: This is just beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate row numbers in two separate queries for parents and children, union the results and concatenate appropriate numbers:

```
with numbers as ( 
    select *, row_number() over (partition by parent_id order by id) as rn
    from person
    where parent_id is not null
    union all
    select *, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
    from person
    where parent_id is null
)
select n1.id, n1.parent_id, concat_ws('.', n2.rn, n1.rn) as number
from numbers as n1
left join numbers as n2 on n2.id = n1.parent_id
order by n1.id

 id | parent_id | number 
----+-----------+--------
  1 |           | 1
  2 |           | 2
  3 |         2 | 2.1
  4 |           | 3
  5 |         4 | 3.1
(5 rows)
```